# MSSql Column aliases in ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a complex query like:

```
SELECT O.OrderNo, 
**COMPLEX SELECT** as Total
FROM Order O

ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 'Ascending' THEN 1
      ELSE
           CASE 
                WHEN @SortBy = 'Total' THEN Total
           END
      END ASC,
      CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 'Descending' THEN 1
      ELSE
           CASE 
                WHEN @SortBy = 'Total' THEN Total
           END
      END DESC
```

But i get "Invalid column name Total". 
I am using Sql Server 2016.

Why i can't order by an alias? I don't want to use indexes.

Comment: You cannot do it on MySQL. But you can re-write your complex select on the order by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with CTE:

```
WITH [Temp] AS (
SELECT O.OrderNo, 
**COMPLEX SELECT** as Total
FROM Order O
)
SELECT * 
FROM Temp
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 'Ascending' THEN 1
      ELSE
           CASE 
                WHEN @SortBy = 'Total' THEN Total
           END
      END ASC,
      CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 'Descending' THEN 1
      ELSE
           CASE 
                WHEN @SortBy = 'Total' THEN Total
           END
      END DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do by using sub-query or  cte

```
select  * from (select *,'' total from orders)A
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 'Ascending' THEN 1
      ELSE
           CASE 
                WHEN @SortBy = 'Total' THEN Total
           END
      END ASC,
      CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 'Descending' THEN 1
      ELSE
           CASE 
                WHEN @SortBy = 'Total' THEN Total
           END
      END DESC
```

Comment: I think you mean CTE instead of recursive cte.